# Как создается массив, почему через new?

Tags: java, массивы

Почему при создании массива используется new, так же как при создании обьекта:

```
int[ ] a = new int [100]; //если так, то обьект a экземпляр какого класса
```

Почему не так:

```
int[ ] a = 100;
```

Comment: Потому что ``int[] a = 100`` - присвоение значения (в данном случае непонятно чему). Лучше спросите, почему не ``int[] a = int [100]``.

Comment: В Java все массивы - объекты. https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/array-primitive-type-object-java/

Comment: При использовании конструкции `new` JVM выделяет память под объект (или массив) в области памяти, называемой куча (heap). Когда же вы используете запись вида `int i=10` JVM создает переменную в области памяти, называемой стек.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Pourquoi pas*? Возможных вариантов синтаксиса создания массива много

```
int[] a = new int[100];
int[] a = int[100];
int[] a = [100];
```

, выбрали какой-то один, так сложилось исторически.

В каком-нибудь другом языке могли бы выбрать и Ваш вариант, но в контексте Java у него есть существенные недостатки:

- для массива используется то же значение, что и для числа, что приводит к путанице:

  ```
  //переменная и создание массива могут быть на разных строках
  int[] a;
  int b;
  //много кода
  a = 100; //догадайтесь, что из них что
  b = 100;

  //еще веселее с элементами массива
  a[0] = 100;
  a = 100; //забыл квадратные скобки и весь массив пересоздан.
  ```
- нет [очевидной] возможности сразу заполнить массив

  ```
  //сейчас можно так:
  int[] a = new int[]{1,2,3};
  //и так
  someMethod(new int[]{1,2,3});

  //а будет
  int[] a = 3; //???
  someMethod(3); //???
  ```
- непонятно как создавать массивы массивов:

  ```
  //сейчас
  int[][] a = new int[100][];

  //потом
  a = ???
  ```

Судя по всему, Вы несколько путаете объявление переменной (`int[] a`) и создание массива (`new int[100]`) с чем и связаны недостатки. Это две разные операции, которые могут выполняться отдельно друг от друга.

Все эти недостатки можно так или иначе обойти (добавить условия, спецсимволы и т.д.) и получить годный к употреблению синтаксис. Но на вопрос: «почему делается так, а не иначе?» ответ будет тот же: «Так сложилось исторически».

Answer (score 2):

Создание массива производится с помощью следующей конструкции: `new тип_данных[количество_элементов]`, где `new` - ключевое слово, выделяющее память для указанного в скобках количества элементов. Например, `nums = new int[4];` - в этом выражении создается массив из четырех элементов `int`, и каждый элемент будет иметь значение по умолчанию - число 0.

Comment: а почему перед nums не поставили тип